# open terminal of a file in Terminal package in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I installed Terminal package in Sublime text3.
What I'd like to do is open up a terminal of a file.
That is if my project root is `src` under `[some directories]` of my home directory and there are many subfolers.

`~/[some directories]/src/` is my project root of sublime

There is a path to the java code: 
`~/[some directories]/src/dir1/dir2/dir3/Test.java`

What I'd like to do is if I hit `command + shift + t`, it opens up a terminal of `~/[some directories]/src/dir1/dir2/dir3/` so that I can work on this directory.

BUT if I hit `command + shift + t`, the terminal path is the current project root ( which is `~/[some directories]/src`) so I need to type `cd dir1/dir2/dir3/` in the terminal. This is annoying.

The current key bindings for Terminal package are

Default(OSX).sublime-keymap -- Terminal (Key-Bindings for Default):

```
[
   { "keys": ["Command+Option+Shift+t"], "command": "open_terminal" },
   { "keys": ["Command+Shift+t"], "command": "open_terminal_project_folder" },
]
```

Default(OSX).sublime-keymap -- User (Key-Bindings for User): is empty

I tweak this and that and googled it but couldn't find a correct key binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to 'Preferences->Packages->Terminal->Settings - User'
you can specify parameters to the terminal you start.

On windows with cmder terminal I have:

```
{
    // The command to execute for the terminal, leave blank for the OS default
    // On OS X the terminal can be set to iTerm.sh to execute iTerm
    "terminal": "C:\\morten\\bin\\cmder\\Cmder.exe",

    // A list of default parameters to pass to the terminal, this can be
    // overridden by passing the "parameters" key with a list value to the args
    // dict when calling the "open_terminal" or "open_terminal_project_folder"
    // commands
    "parameters": ["/START", "%CWD%"]
}
```

Should be easily adjustable to your OS/terminal.

This will always start cmder in the directory of the file you are currently viewing, when running open_terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

Comment: it's not working. i tried and that. when I open a terminal, it shows the full path where the code is for a very short time, and then it set back to project root.  that is `~/[some directories]/src/dir1/dir2/dir3/` is displayed on the terminal path for a very short time during the terminal is being opening like less than 1 sec. But when the terminal opening is done, it shows a project src in the path(`~/[some directories]/src/).

Comment: Which terminal (OS) are you using, and is it possible to try another terminal?